# How to use "and" to connect three verbs?

Tags: grammar, reduced-relative-clauses

Here is my question.

> A burning stream of whisky ran through the streets of Dublin's central district, **stretching** over four hundred meters and reaching up to two feet wide and six inches deep.

Why should we use "stretching" here? Is it because there a connective, such as "and" deleted, causing a participle construction?

Comment: Generally "and" connects similar items (grammatically speaking). I can't explain why using stretching here is correct (have to look up my grammar books - although I know by experience it's correct -). Also, what else do you think could be used instead of stretching?

Comment: Could be that [which was] *stretching* continues the tone of *burning*. There's no *and* implied.

Comment: They partied late, dancing and ______ . (a) eat / (b₁) ate / (b₂) eaten / (c) eating / (d) to eat?

Comment: I'm surprised the report didn't use "running" instead of "run" -- news writers have been told to always use "ing" verbs to convey urgency, immediacy or something.
I would have left out "reaching" because stretching already says the same thing: "A burning stream of whisky ran through the streets of Dublin's central district, stretching over four hundred meters (long), up to two feet wide, and six inches deep."

Answer (score 0):

The word "*reaching*" is used here to correspond with "*stretching*" as the comment by USER jsnjdhs  suggests. The sentence could have been written using "*that stretched*" in place of  "*stretching*", in which case "*reached*" would have been used after the "*and*". The entire sentence would have been:

> A burning stream of whisky ran through the streets of Dublin's central district, that stretched over four hundred meters and reached up to two feet wide and six inches deep.

Other variants would also have been possible, conveying much the same meaning.

Note that the "*and*" after "four hundred meters" is not connecting three verbs, it is connecting two phrases: "*stretching over four hundred meters*" and "*reaching up to two feet wide and six inches deep*"

Answer (score 0):

It's common in English for "-ing" verbs to replace certain *subordinate clause* structures.

Another way to write the same sentence is:

> A burning stream of whisky ran through the streets of Dublin's central district, **which stretched** over four hundred meters and **reached** up to two feet wide and six inches deep.

More examples of an "-ing" verb replacing different structures:

> **Because he was** independently wealthy, he didn't have to work.
>
> **Being** independently wealthy, he didn't have to work.

> **When he arrived home**, Solomon found his wife, Minerva, entertaining a neighbor.
>
> **Arriving home**, Solomon found his wife, Minerva, entertaining a neighbor.

Comment: That word order can confuse the reader about what is stretched -- proximity means some will read it as "....the central district, which stretched four hundred meters..."

Comment: @user8356 True, the version with "-ing" is clearer. I don't think it affects the answer to the question though, which is about using "-ing" to replace subordinate clause structures.